# Weird thing with WKWebView subviews

Tags: ios, objective-c, wkwebview

I have a `viewController` that holds `WKWebView` in his properties.

I made my `viewController` to implement `UIScrollViewDelegate` and in 'didScroll' put some code that wont let the `scrollView` scroll vertically.
like that:

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(scrollView.contentOffset.x, 0);
}
```

- The disabling part is good I tried it on other `scrollView` and it works just fine.

I set the `webView.scrollView` delegate to be the `viewController`.

I also made a method that loop over all of the `subViews` of `webView` and if it comes across another `scrollView` it set the `delegate` of that `scrollView` to be the `viewController`.

After all that it still not working...

```
-(void)setDelegateForScrollViewsInView:(UIView *)view{
if (view.subviews.count > 0) {
    for (UIView *subView in view.subviews){
        if ([subView isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]]) {
            [((UIScrollView *)subView) setDelegate:self];
            [((UIScrollView *)subView) setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:false];
            [((UIScrollView *)subView) setBackgroundColor:UIColor.blueColor];
        }

        [self setDelegateForScrollViewsInView:subView];
    }
}I    }
```

After `View Debugger` i found that my `webView` is build up in that hirarchy:

[image: webView]

And my method cant catches the inside `scrollView` so the disabling of the vertical scroll won't work.

How can I fix it?

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28703592) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28631317)

Comment: Hi Craig. Thank you for your answer, but this answer is not what I looking for. I'm trying to disable only vertical scrooling.