# WKWebView inside Scroll View

Tags: ios, swift, webview, scroll

How can I put a WKWebView inside a Scroll View consider that I must have others elements after Web View.

`. View
... Scroll View
....... ImageView
....... WKWebView
....... Button`

[See the demo image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7BGUU.png)

- Issue 1: Disable scroll for WKWebView
- Issue 2: Set full content height for WKWebView

Check my [sample project](https://github.com/alanbarboza/Dynamic)

Comment: See this question for disabling scroll: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28631317/how-to-disable-scrolling-entirely-in-a-wkwebview/31902046

Comment: I didn't understand the part `with elements after Web View`. Could you make it a bit clearer?

Comment: Please read this then edit your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve you should make it as easy as possible for people to help you.

Comment: @Mosbah I already try it, but the scroll be locked on WBWebView and doesn't fill the full height of their content

Comment: @Glenn I have update the question text, sorry

Comment: @Magnas thanks, I've updated the text of question.. I'm sorry

Comment: Check my answer, @AlanBarboza

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you mean to get the content height of the html in `WKWebView` to make it non-scrollable inside `UIScrollView`, then read on.

You need to observe (via delegate) the content height of your webView. I'm giving you these steps, since you quite know what you're doing, and you're almost there.

**Make an outlet out of your webView height constraint**

```
@IBOutlet weak var constraint_WebViewHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

**Subscribe to webView's delegate**

This will let you know (your controller when your webView has finished loading the contents of your site.

```
self.webView.navigationDelegate = self
```

**Conform to protocol**

Inside the `didFinish navigation` method of `WKNavigationDelegate`, you then adjust the constant of your webView height constraint. Put some animation if you want to :)

```
extension ViewController: WKNavigationDelegate {
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) {
            self.constraint_WebViewHeight.constant = webView.scrollView.contentSize.height
        }
    }
}
```

**Finally, fix your constraints.**

a. Remove your imageView bottom constraint.
b. Add bottom constraint to your save button to the scrollView.

This will make your scrollView scrollable.

Voila! This yields this result.

[image]

I hope this helps!

Comment: It really solve the problem, I'm so grateful.. Thanks!

Comment: Application will be crashing due to memory impacts if you will try load page with a lot of images

Comment: I can't reach a value for constraint_WebViewHeight. I followed the tutorial but somethings is yet wrong. Perhaps the constraints of the views? Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by you couldn't "reach a value"? @papesky?

Comment: I mean that the constraint_WebViewHeight is null and I don't know if I must link the IBOutlet to the same webView or what... :(

Comment: Read again the answer, @papesky, and you should know. Read it carefully. It says that you need indeed to link the HEIGHT of the webView to an IBOutlet in the code.

Comment: Heads up that a random `asyncAfter(now() + 0.1...` is a giveaway that this is a hack (though a working one for most devices). Another hacky approach is doing KVO on the scrollview contentSize, i'll add answer for this now

Comment: I bet it'll be fine if you remove that delay.

Answer (score 1):

Same approach as Glenn's answer - it still manually adjusts a height constraint on the `WKWebView` - but this approach avoids the `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter()`. I wanted to avoid it because if `DispatchQueue.main.async()` doesn't work, and it did not, then you're waiting an indeterminate amount of time -- not good.

```
    fileprivate var webviewHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint?
    fileprivate var observer: NSKeyValueObservation?
    fileprivate weak var webview: WKWebView?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      // set self.webview to your webview
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        self.startObservingContentSize(webview: self.webview)
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        self.stopObservingContentSize()
    }

    // song & dance to get WKWebview in a UIScrollView
    private var _lastContentSize: CGSize?
    fileprivate func startObservingContentSize(webview: WKWebView) {
        let handler = { [weak webview, weak self] (scrollview: UIScrollView, change: NSKeyValueObservedChange<CGSize>) in
            if let self = self, let webview = webview, let contentSize = change.newValue {
                if self._lastContentSize?.height == contentSize.height { return }
                self._lastContentSize = contentSize
                self.webviewHeightConstraint?.isActive = false
                self.webviewHeightConstraint = webview.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: contentSize.height)
                self.webviewHeightConstraint?.isActive = true
                self.contentView?.setNeedsLayout()
            }
        }
        self.observer = webview.scrollView.observe(\UIScrollView.contentSize, options: [NSKeyValueObservingOptions.new], changeHandler: handler)
    }

    fileprivate func stopObservingContentSize() {
        self.observer?.invalidate()
        self.observer = nil
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the understanding you want webview not to scroll well if the page is bigger than your screen it will scroll right? 
To show the full page. Although you can change the isscrollingenabled to false from  interface builder or from code by using object of scrollview. 
To set full height give constraint 0,0,0,0 from all sides and it will surely stretch to whole screen

Comment: Now the scroll of WKWebView stay locked, but the height of WKWebView stay fixed... I have pushed the changes to project in Github

Comment: @AlanBarboza I'm posting my answer in 1 min.

Comment: thats a long minute

Answer (score -1):

It's wrong approach.
You should use WKWebView's scrollView.

You need reserve space for image and button with html margins using javascript

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.body.style.margin = '%dpx %dpx %dpx %dpx'", (int)margins.top, (int)margins.right, (int)margins.bottom, (int)margins.left]
```

or directly in html body if you able to access it.

Add imageview and button into WKWebView's scrollView.

Comment: There is no good solution anyway but this won't work at all with autolayout as e.g. in my case i don't know those margins.

Comment: @Injectios you can observer frames with KVO and update margins if changed

Comment: Yes, thanks, thats what i'm doing, however it's not very reliable thing to do as it really depends which HTML is there. I feel like i've been trying to make work perfectly together two different ecosystems xd. Sadly it is not possible atm.

Comment: @Injectios `<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no'>` makes two ecosystems friendly