# WkWebview inside uiScrollview

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiscrollview, wkwebview

I was wondering if you can help me please. I have a wkWebview that has horizontal paging content.

Outside of that I have a scroll view that also has horizontal paging content.

There is obviously a conflict when scrolling and I was wondering what is best to solve the issue.

I want a continuous scroll that when scrolling on the web view that has a content offset less than 0 I want to scroll the parent scroll view to the page before. When the content offset is greater than the size of the content size I want to go to the next page.

I considered using a pan gesture recognizer. However I can’t seem to get it working properly.

When the web view decides to call the parent setContentOffset method how do I make sure that it behaviours like it is paying the content?

Hopefully that makes sense.

Please help.

Comment: Well, perhaps it will help you [WKWebview inside ScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54270287/wkwebview-inside-scroll-view)

Comment: Thanks. I saw that one but it’s not quite the same. I have a horizontal wkwebview that has five pages of content and a uiScrollview that contains five other views. I want to have ten pages of content but feel like it’s one big scrollview. Hope that makes sense ?